# Hide attribute of an element from DOM

Tags: javascript, attributes, hidden

As the title says, I would like to add a new hidden attribute to an element. To avoid any confusion, I want the attribute to be hidden, not the element.

I have a div: `<div id="hello_div">Hello!</div>`

I add an attribute: `$('#hello_div').attr('my_attr', 'attr_value');`

So I can get it later: `var v = $('#hello_div').attr('my_attr');`

It works as expected but if you inspect the `div` in the DOM Explorer, you see:

`<div id="hello_div" my_attr="attr_value">Hello!</div>`

Is there any way to hide this attribute?

Comment: I think you can't hide it from dom.

Comment: you need to remove it

Comment: Try removeattribute as described [here] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_removeattribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't hide DOM-attributes, but as I see you are using jQuery, you could try `data`. E.g.

```
$('#hello_div').data('my_attr', 'attr_value');
```

and later retrieve:

```
var v = $('#hello_div').data('my_attr');
```

Comment: any vanilla javascript solution?

Answer (score 2):

When you get back your required attribute `var v = $('#hello_div').attr('my_attr');`

remove the attribute after this `$('#hello_div').removeAttr('my_attr');`

Answer (score 0):

No. If you manipulate the DOM by adding an attribute, it will always be visible when using a DOM inspector like Chrome developer tools etc.